Export GTiff to PNG
I'm trying to export a raster as a PNG file only for visualization purposes. Currently, gdalinfo -stats shows this:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ./downloads/2023-06-01.tiff
Size is 764, 693
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 34N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",21,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Navigation and medium accuracy spatial referencing."],
        AREA["Between 18┬░E and 24┬░E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84┬░N, onshore and offshore. Albania. Belarus. Bosnia and Herzegovina. Bulgaria. Central African Republic. Chad. Croatia. Democratic Republic of the Congo (Zaire). Estonia. Finland. Greece. Hungary. Italy. Kosovo. Latvia. Libya. Lithuania. Montenegro. North Macedonia. Norway, including Svalbard and Bjornoys. Poland. Romania. Russian Federation. Serbia. Slovakia. Sudan. Sweden. Ukraine."],
        BBOX[0,18,84,24]],
    ID["EPSG",32634]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (256905.823021741322009,4729970.997584735043347)
Pixel Size = (9.998823865457565,-9.998823865457918)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  LAYOUT=COG
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  256905.823, 4729970.998) ( 18d 1'58.20"E, 42d41' 1.66"N)
Lower Left  (  256905.823, 4723041.813) ( 18d 2' 8.87"E, 42d37'17.31"N)
Upper Right (  264544.924, 4729970.998) ( 18d 7'33.46"E, 42d41'10.21"N)
Lower Right (  264544.924, 4723041.813) ( 18d 7'43.79"E, 42d37'25.85"N)
Center      (  260725.374, 4726506.405) ( 18d 4'51.08"E, 42d39'13.79"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1139.000 Max=9008.000
  Minimum=1139.000, Maximum=9008.000, Mean=1746.716, StdDev=591.403
  NoData Value=0
  Overviews: 382x346, 191x173
  Offset: -0.1,   Scale:0.0001
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=9008
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1746.716236827
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1139
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=591.40277752517
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=52.01
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=1252.000 Max=8172.000
  Minimum=1252.000, Maximum=8172.000, Mean=1771.756, StdDev=451.360
  NoData Value=0
  Overviews: 382x346, 191x173
  Offset: -0.1,   Scale:0.0001
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=8172
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1771.7560626639
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1252
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=451.36044017007
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=52.01
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=1267.000 Max=7508.000
  Minimum=1267.000, Maximum=7508.000, Mean=1718.591, StdDev=353.460
  NoData Value=0
  Overviews: 382x346, 191x173
  Offset: -0.1,   Scale:0.0001
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=7508
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1718.5911996049
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1267
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=353.46019405266
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=52.01

This raster looks good on QGIS (first attached picture shows QGIS with the range stretched to min/max) but converting it to PNG via gdal_translate as in gdal_translate -a_scale 0.0001 -a_offset -0.1 -of PNG downloads\2023-06-01.tiff dubrovnik.png  returns an extremely dark, that can be seen in the second attached picture. I have to explicitly set the scale and offset since the -unscale flag returns an empty image (all transparent pixels). Instead of stretching to min/max in the PNG, returning it within a normal range would be nice as well.
I have a feeling that these problems have to do with data range and something weird with scale and offset.
I would like as well, if possible, to remove the georeferencing and just get the rotated rectangle that contains the image (no transparent pixels), even if it means losing data or resampling, not sure if possible only with GDAL but I'm using Python, so rasterio or rioxarray are also options for me.



what happens if you don't specify any scaling at all - gdal_translate downloads\2023-06-01.tiff dubrovnik.png

at first sight, exactly the same thing, a very dark image with the transparent borders

What are the min/max values reported by gdalinfo 2023-06-01.tiff -stats?

I just edited the question to add this information :-)

Read https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-scale. Just using -scale without other parameters should fit the values between min/max of the source on the range 0-255 of the output 8-bit png. In not, give the desired values for scaling explicitly. It is good to read all parts of the documentation, "scale" does not work exactly as user might suppose.
Documentation:

Rescale the input pixels values from the range src_min to src_max to
the range dst_min to dst_max. If omitted the output range is 0 to 255.
If omitted the input range is automatically computed from the source
dataset, in its whole (not just the window of interest potentially
specified with -srcwin or -projwin). This may be a slow operation on a
large source dataset, and if using it multiple times for several
gdal_translate invocation, it might be beneficial to call gdalinfo
-stats {source_dataset} priorly to precompute statistics, for formats that support serializing statistics computations (GeoTIFF, VRT...)
Note that the values specified after -scale are only used to compute a
scale and offset to apply to the input raster values. In particular,
src_min and src_max are not used to clip input values. -scale can be
repeated several times (if specified only once, it also applies to all
bands of the output dataset), so as to specify per band parameters. It
is also possible to use the "-scale_bn" syntax where bn is a band
number (e.g. "-scale_2" for the 2nd band of the output dataset) to
specify the parameters of one or several specific bands.


thank you, you're right, using -scale with no parameters solved it. I had to add -ot Byte as well for the PNG output
